# Is it possible to define the value of the centre of a polar plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to define the very centre of my polar plot, as some value other than $0$.

I have tried a mixture of commands, including `PlotRange` but this behaves more like `ImagePadding` in `ListPolarPlot`. I thought `PolarAxesOrigin` might do the trick but that just changes the position of the radial axis in the circular plot and the upper bound -- it always seems to have the radial axis start at $0$

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation, but I wonder if anyone knows of a trick?

---

Here's a primitive example:

```
ListPolarPlot[
 Transpose[{Table[n π, {n, 0, 2, 0.1}] , 
   Table[R, {R, -1, 1, 0.1}] }], PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees",Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True]
```

I would instead like the origin to be at $-1$, thus changing the profile or viewing perspective of the curve. Simply relabelling the axis would not achieve this.

Comment: Do you only care about the *labels* on the plot?  Or something else?  Some more detail might be necessary (like an example of the function you are trying to plot).

Comment: I have added some more information. I think the best way to view it is I want to change the "viewing perspective" so rather than looking up at 0, one looks up at -1.

Comment: ... or this: `MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, -1}]] &, lpp, {1}]`?

Comment: @kglr No, the origin and centre of the polar plot is still 0?...hang on I have some missing options in my above code -- my mistake...

Comment: @I missied the options to make it look like a proper polar plot. So I guess what you did for me is half there but to have the R axis start at -1 in the centre of the circle.

Comment: how about this: `ListPolarPlot[
 Transpose[{Table[n \[Pi], {n, 0, 2, 0.1}], 
   Table[R, {R, -1, 1, 0.1}]}], PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", 
   Transpose[{Subdivide[0, 1, 4], Subdivide[-1, 1., 4]}]}, 
 PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, Subdivide[0, 1, 4]}]`?

Comment: @kglr is this not just a relabelling of axis? The plot itself should look different depending on the centre origin right? The observer's "perspective should" change. I'll see if I can make a simple example using a circle.